# Mount folder as a volume (OSX)

Tags: macos, filesystem, mount, disk-volume

Is it possible to (auto) 'mount' folders as Volumes?
I have a large DAS Volume, 'Data', that contains all my data.
To make paths shorter and more future proof, I'd like to have Volumes like

/ContentTypeA/
/ContentTypeB/

Instead of using

/Data/ContentTypeA/
/Data/ContentTypeB/

etc, which is where the data actually resides.

Any ideas on how to do that? It's not a big problem. Just curious.

Comment: Does the answer to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/84222/is-there-a-disk-volume-substitute-command-in-osx-similar-to-subst-on-windows (which recommends the use of symbolic links or aliases) solve your problem?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with either. I.e. doing either cd /ContentTypeA/ or cd /ContentTypeA/existingfolder just says 'no such file or directory'. :(

Comment: There will be no folders unless you create them :-)

Comment: For Catalina, the answer is given here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372500/119397  -- see "man synthetic.conf"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's assume you are mounting/attaching your Data drive as usual which will result in paths like `/Volumes/Data/ContentA` and `/Volumes/Data/ContentB`. You can now do either of:

- create symbolic links via Terminal running the following commands in a Terminal window:

  ```
  ln -s /Volumes/Data/ContentA ~/ContentA
  ln -s /Volumes/Data/ContentB ~/ContentB
  ```
- create aliases via Finder by opening `/Volumes/Data` in Finder, selecting `ContentA`, pressing <kbd>Cmd-L</kbd> to create an alias and moving this alias to your Home folder. The alias file can afterwards be renamed as you see fit.

With both options the content of the Data drive will be accessible via your Home folder.

Comment: That works. :) Combining it with the home folder solved it. Thanks a lot patrix!

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes symbolic links may not be suitable for your needs.

In that cases you can use [bindfs](http://bindfs.org) - a FUSE filesystem for mounting a directory to another location.

Install it with [homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew install bindfs
```

And then bind one folder to another:

```
bindfs /Volumes/Data/ContentA ~/ContentA
```

Comment: cool thanks, is this different than the mount command on linux? or is this basically a port of the mount command to MacOS?

Comment: @AlexanderMills bindfs is a FUSE filesystem for mounting a directory to another location. It's not mount command.

Comment: When I run brew install bindfs I see: Error: bindfs has been disabled because it requires closed-source macFUSE!

Answer (score 8):

I just wanna say thanks to @mixel - that is THE WAY to do it, I actually wanted to mount the iCloud Drive as a volume, so that it appears on the desktop.

Installation of bindfs did not go that easy on Sierra, I had to do the following:

```
brew cask install osxfuse
brew install homebrew/fuse/bindfs
```

and then in my case I might add that the handy relevant bindfs option is `-o volumename=NAME`, otherwise the volume gets some crazy name that hurts eyes.

And for anyone who'd like to have the iCloud Drive appear as a volume, the sequence is this:

```
sudo mkdir /Volumes/iCloud\ Drive
sudo bindfs -o volname=iCloud\ Drive /Users/robert/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs \
        /Volumes/iCloud\ Drive/
```

Comment: Disadvantage of fuse is that it do not support inotify events.   
If source updated, while App watching for updates in destination, it will not receive updates.

Comment: Two comments: 1) You have to do it every time the session restarts. 2) The Volume is not showing up in the volume list in the sideBar. Would you know a workaround?

Answer (score 6):

Update for 2021 on High Sierra:

Trying to install `bindfs` on MacOS today, using the examples above, I got this error:

```
Error: bindfs has been disabled because it requires closed-source macFUSE!
```

Bummer.  (Don't you just hate it when someone else's ideology interferes with your technology?)

But thanks to: https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/801 I was finally able to workaround that, and install bindfs from here:

```
brew install gromgit/fuse/bindfs-mac
```