# Mount Folder in Maverick

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, mount, alias

I want to mount a folder to another folder. My reasoning is:
I have a free box.net account with 50GB, but it does not include versioning. So I would like to put the folder under git. But I do not want to sync the .git folder in the box folder itself to avoiud synching.

Git does not recognise links and alias as links and aliases and does version these as such, and not the folders underneath. But a mounted folder should be visible as a folder. So:

Is there a way to mount a folder in OSX as one can in Linux [Linux](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/mount-a-local-folder-510334/) using:

```
mount --bin /PATH/TO/ORIGINAL/ORIGINALFOLDER /PATH/TO/MOUNTPOINT
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mount folder as a volume (OSX)](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97920/mount-folder-as-a-volume-osx)

Comment: No - as the one you are linking to has been answered by using links / alias, where in my case this does not work (tried it out).

Comment: How is your http://box.net account mounted on your Mac – nfs? Have you investigated using `autofs` for mounting to a specific path?

Comment: I am using the Box Sync app (https://sites.box.com/sync4/), and I would like to continue using it.