# Why am I getting an error "No Index" when I try to CREATE a spotlight index with mdutil?

Tags: network, spotlight

I'm trying to create a spolight index of a directory on a shared drive (a corporate Windows active directory drive) using `mdutil` following [the simple guide here](https://jonathansblog.co.uk/how-to-enable-spotlight-indexing-on-a-network-drive). Here's an example of my syntax:

```
mdutil "/Volumes/volName/Directory/Directory Containing Spaces/Another Directory" -i on
```

The error message I get confuses me:

> Error: invalid operation.
>
> No index.

I know there's no index, I'm running this command in order to create one.

How am I getting a "no index" error on a command that should create an index? Is there some step I'm missing?

Comment: How do you mount the network drive? With afp or smb?

Comment: ------- It's `smb`

Answer (score 1):

Indexing can be enabled or disabled only on the root of the drive, so, "/Volumes/volName". You can read more about the command by typing `man mdutil` into the terminal. An excerpt:

> -i on | off:
>   Sets the indexing status for the provided volumes to on or off.  Note that indexing may be delayed due to low disk space or other conditions.

Also, indexing won't work on a drive mounted with SMB. You will have to use AFP in order to do so.

Comment: Huh, not good, that drive is massive. Is there any way to index just one directory?

Comment: This looks promising http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97920/mount-folder-as-a-volume-osx

Comment: Actually, no, that looks no good, but this looks promising https://m.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/2s9tdq/is_it_possible_to_mount_a_local_shared_folder_as/