# Mount two disks/directories into a single point

Tags: filesystem, mount

I want to mount two disks or directories into a single mount point. I saw some article online which mentioned **bindfs**, I had a look at it but I don't understand how it can help.

[Another article](https://aplawrence.com/foo-mac/union-mounts.html) shows how to mount two disks into a single directory using this mount option: **-o union**. I tried those instructions and they don't seem to work.

My goal is to mount a disk into an existing directory of an already mounted disk and see both files from the mounted disk and the directory.

Edit:

The solution proposed is not working, the content of the disk hides the content of the target directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mount folder as a volume (OSX)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97920/mount-folder-as-a-volume-osx)

Comment: I don't see how this is the same issue, I want to keep the existing file from the mount point alongside the files from the mounted disk.

Comment: Look at the second solution using `bindfs`

Comment: `bindfs /Volumes/Disk ~/TargetDirectory` It does not work, the files inside the second directory are being hidden by the content of the disk. I am asking for a solution which merges the two contents.