# Mount folder as another folder in iOS (darwin17), like mount -o bind or bindfs?

Tags: ios, ipad, mount, python

I have to communicate folders from one app to another in a Jailbroken device. Unfortunately my app cannot deal with symlinks, and I have too many files to do hard links on all of them.

The only way to do it (as I know) would be to mount the folder as a Volume, like mount -o bind /dirsource /dirdestiny (in linux), or bindfs in MacOS. But iOS didn't have such tools.

I cannot do what they said in
[Mount folder as a volume (OSX)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97920/mount-folder-as-a-volume-osx) because it only comprises MacOS.

Note: I have Python 3 installed with c compiler, so I'm able to install almost any pip3 package. If there is a way to do it using python would be good too.

How is the way to do that on iOS?