# Running apropos causes error on macos with makewhatis

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina, unix

Can anyone help me troubleshoot what's wrong with my environment? Heres some basic information, i'll add any needed information.

```
MacOS Catalina 10.15.2 (19C57)
MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018)
```

### `cjensen@Aerith-MBP:~|⇒ apropos ls`

---

```
makewhatis: /usr/lib/./libgutenprint.2.dylib: No such file or directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.0.1.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libldap.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcom_err.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libresolv.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libnetsnmpagent.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libMatch.1.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpam.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/charset.alias: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libipsec.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libsysdiagnose.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libgermantok.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libz.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libBSDPClient.A.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libc.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libgutenprint.2.dylib: No such file or directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libMatch.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcrypto.44.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libauto.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcoreroutine.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpcap.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libquit.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpmsample.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcupsimage.2.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libipsec.A.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libextension.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpoll.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libxar.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/liblapack.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libIASUnifiedProgress.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcoretls.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libdz.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libnetsnmptrapd.25.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libobjc.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libclapack.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/ACIPCBTLib.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libBSDPClient.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libtls.6.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libtls.16.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libperfcheck.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libf77lapack.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libXplugin.1.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libmx.A.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpcreposix.0.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libz.1.2.11.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libz.1.2.8.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libproc.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.5.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libAudioStatistics.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libexslt.0.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpanel.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libexpat.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcurses.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcharset.1.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libtailspin.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcrypto.42.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libiconv.2.4.0.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libMemoryResourceException.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libnetsnmp.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libnetsnmptrapd.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libspindump.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libecpg.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libdes425.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libbz2.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libimg4_development.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpcre.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/librpcsvc.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libktrace.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libAppleSSEExt.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/dsc_extractor.bundle: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libxpc_datastores.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpcre.0.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libnetsnmpagent.25.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libutil1.0.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libmecab.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libiodbcinst.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libapr-1.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libATCommandStudioDynamic.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libarchive.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libsystemstats.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libtcl8.5.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libssl.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libecpg.6.5.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libauditd.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/dyld: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/PN548.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libncurses.5.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libiodbc.2.1.18.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libiodbcinst.2.1.18.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libdtrace.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libChineseTokenizer.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libnetsnmp.25.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libssl.35.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpcreposix.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libinfo.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libtzupdate.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libedit.3.0.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libCRFSuite0.12.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libtls.15.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpanel.5.4.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcsfde.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.0.15.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libecpg.6.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libMaxEnt.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libmorphun.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libheimdal-asn1.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/PN548_API.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libkrb5support.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libsandbox.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libkrb524.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libiconv.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libsasl2.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcrypto.41.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libXplugin.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcrypto.35.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libxml2.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libDHCPServer.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libz.1.2.5.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpgtypes.3.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libform.5.4.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libedit.3.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libhunspell-1.2.0.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libform.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libtk8.5.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libMTLCapture.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpgtypes.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libParallelCompression.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcupsimage.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libnetworkextension.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libssl.43.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libFDR_osx.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcblas.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libmarisa.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libdscsym.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libAudioToolboxUtility.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libAudioIssueDetector.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libkrb4.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libnfstorage.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libimg4.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpq.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libThaiTokenizer.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libdbm.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libodmodule.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libXSEvent.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libsysmon.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcharset.1.0.0.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libiodbc.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libate.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libScreenReader.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libgmalloc.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libtk.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libc++.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libiodbc.2.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpq.5.6.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libecpg_compat.3.5.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libIOReport.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libblas.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libQMIParserDynamic.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libffi-trampolines.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libncurses.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/liblzma.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libtcl.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.0.22.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpthread.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libSecRecord.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libffi.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libEndpointSecurity.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libCoreStorage.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libboringssl.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcurl.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libnfrestore.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libdl.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libCTGreenTeaLogger.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libSMC.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libicucore.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libusrtcp.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libAppletTranslationLibrary.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libodfde.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libapp_launch_measurement.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcups.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libxcselect.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libutil.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libtermcap.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libnetsnmphelpers.25.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libprequelite.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libipconfig.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcharset.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libtls.18.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libruby.2.6.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcurl.3.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libIOAccessoryManager.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libruby.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libldap_r.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libkrb5.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libnetsnmpmibs.25.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libbsm.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libedit.2.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libecpg_compat.3.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libeasyperf.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libIASAuthReboot.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpmenergy.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libdns_services.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libfakelink.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/liblber.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libexpat.1.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libIOGTrace.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libreadline.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libhunspell-1.2.0.0.0.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/ssh-keychain.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libssl.46.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libtidy.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libapple_nghttp2.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.0.21.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libnetsnmpmibs.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libAccountPolicyTranslation.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libmenu.5.4.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpgtypes.3.4.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libxslt.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libk5crypto.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpython.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libhunspell-1.2.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libUniversalAccess.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libDHCPServer.A.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libpam.1.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libm.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libmx.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/PN548_HAL.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libmenu.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libedit.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libapr-1.0.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libz.1.1.3.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libnetsnmphelpers.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/AppleConvergedTransport.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libnfshared.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libexslt.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libecpg_compat.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libauditd.0.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libiodbcinst.2.dylib: Not a directory
makewhatis: /usr/lib/libssl.44.dylib: Not a directory
tch from terminals
term_send(n), term::send(n) - General output to terminals
tlsmgr(8)                - Postfix TLS session cache and PRNG manager
tlsproxy(8)              - Postfix TLS proxy
topsyscall(1m)           - top syscalls by syscall name. Uses DTrace
topsysproc(1m)           - top syscalls by process name. Uses DTrace
tpool(n)                 - Part of the Tcl threading extension implementing pools of worker threads
traptoemail(1)           - snmptrapd handler script to convert snmp traps into emails
unstack(n)               - Unstacking channels
variables(5)             - Format of specifying variable names to SNMP tools
xcode-select(1)          - Manages the active developer directory for Xcode and BSD tools. rst2man-indent-level 0 1 rstReportMargin \$1 \n[an-margin] level \n[rst2man-indent-level] level margin: \n[rst2man-indent\n[rst2man-indent-level]] - \n[rst2man-indent0] \n[rst2man-indent1] \n[rst2man-indent2] . 1 INDENT RS \$1 nr rst2man-indent\n[rst2man-indent-level] \n[an-margin] nr rst2man-indent-level +1 . UNINDENT RE rst2man-indent-level -1 \n[rst2man-indent\n[rst2man-indent-level]]u
zero(n)                  - Create and manipulate zero channels
zipdetails(1)            - display the internal structure of zip files
TIFFquery(3tiff), TIFFCurrentRow(3tiff), TIFFCurrentStrip(3tiff), TIFFCurrentTile(3tiff), TIFFCurrentDirectory(3tiff), TIFFLastDirectory(3tiff), TIFFFileno(3tiff), TIFFFileName(3tiff), TIFFGetMode(3tiff), TIFFIsTiled(3tiff), TIFFIsByteSwapped(3tiff), TIFFIsUpSampled(3tiff), TIFFIsMSB2LSB(3tiff), TIFFGetVersion(3tiff) - query routines
sqlsharp(1)              - Mono SQL Query command-line tool
textdomain(3)            - set domain for future gettext() calls
textdomain(3)            - set domain for future gettext() calls
```

Comment: Will this help:https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/375629/341892