# How to add/link a folder directly to /

Tags: xcode, catalina, mount

An Xcode project I'm working on requires it to be copied to root and then run from there for it to work and the problem is that I'm running Catalina which protects the root directory.

I tried to follow the instructions in [How to make root volume writeable again in Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371908/how-to-make-root-volume-writeable-again-in-catalina)

but I don't know how to adapt `echo -e 'bar\tSystem/Volumes/Data/bar' | sudo tee -a /etc/synthetic.conf` to my situation.

I need a solution that can actually mount the project folder on a volume so I can run the project from there or any lateral thinking. Any advice?

Comment: Right now it's unclear why the answers to the two questions you've linked don't work for you. Why does the solution in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371908/how-to-make-root-volume-writeable-again-in-catalina not help? Why isn't a symlink to `/Volumes/something` not an option?

Comment: because I'm not understanding what these lines does -> `echo -e 'bar\tSystem/Volumes/Data/bar' | sudo tee -a /etc/synthetic.conf`

Comment: and i don't even know what is `man synthetic.conf`

Comment: 1) Any project which requires a folder to be copied to `/` is broken (was broken already before Catalina actually) and needs to be fixed in order to rely on paths a normal user can write to

Comment: 2) `man synthetic.conf` is just the command to access the manual page describing the syntax to be used in `synthetic.conf`.

Comment: 3) I've edited your question to reflect the things you've made in the comments. Can you add the current path of the folder in question (how can it be accessed right now) and the name it should have in `/` so people here can make specific suggestions?